# Can't run powerline-config during startup (in .tmux.conf)

Tags: config, tmux, powerline

When I start tmux, I get a failure when trying to configure powerline. I have set an environment environment variable with this:

```
export POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND=`which powerline-config`
```

My `~/.tmux.conf` contains the following:

```
if-shell "POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND" \
  run-shell "$POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND tmux setup"
```

The error I get is:

```
unknown command: /path/to/powerline-config
```

I can run the config command manually after tmux starts with this:

```sh
$POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND tmux setup
```

I don't understand why tmux can't run the command during the startup when it can run just fine afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how you get that error. You should not get any message, and nothing should work.

```
if-shell "POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND" \
  run-shell "$POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND tmux setup"
```

will fail, because `POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND` is not a command. Your `if-shell` should have a `$` in front of `POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND`.

Let's assume that was a typo, and it's correct in your actual `.conf`. Then, **the problem is that `run-shell` runs against `tmux`**, the way it'd run if you typed `<prefix>:` in your tmux session.

`tmux $POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND tmux setup` is not a valid command.

You could instead do

```
   run-shell 'send-keys "$POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND tmux setup" Enter'
```

If you wanted it run in a single pane.

Comment: Your assumption is correct that I had a typo. So I tried what you suggested (`run-shell 'send-keys "$POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND tmux setup" Enter'`) and got the error: `.tmux.conf:58: no current target`. So something isn't quite matching up. I really just want Powerline configured properly for my tmux set up.

Comment: If you reload your tmux.conf after you enter a tmux session, does it work?

Comment: Yes it does. What does that tell us?

Comment: It tells us that `tmux.conf` gets executed before you have any tmux sessions available, and that calling `powerline-config tmux setup` is the wrong way to start powerline for tmux. [This issue](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1566) seems to imply you're supposed to be calling `powerline-daemon` (maybe in your `.bashrc`?) and that will set up tmux stuff for you... maybe. I don't know anything about powerline.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand a little better. I was calling `powerline-daemon` in my `.bashrc`. I read somewhere that I needed to do that. Perhaps I don't. I've changed my `.bashrc` so that now I call `powerline-config tmux setup` and things seem to be working.

Comment: I think you *are* supposed to run `powerline-daemon` in  your `.bashrc`. I *thought* that would just magically work for `tmux` once it detected you were in that environment, and that you didn't need an explicit call to `powerline-config tmux setup` more than once ever. If that didn't work, and running both or just the latter in your `.bashrc` did, then I guess we're good?